# Possible to continuously update text in the notification area?

Tags: android, android-notifications, notification-area

I would like a to place persistent text in the notification area that updates once every second.  setTicker() in the NotificationCompat.Builder class will not work, because it hides everything else in the notification area.  I am only looking to place text there that is a few characters long, taking up only a small piece of the notification area.

One way I think this can be done is by calling setSmallIcon(), and somehow using this small icon area to display text.  I took a screenshot of an app's notification that I believe to be using this strategy.  Notice the 165 KB/s:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the ticker text of the notification to update the user. This text is shown when the notification is posted.

Like the screenshot it uses `setSmallIcon` like you mentioned.

You can create a bitmap and draw text on with the canvas API, [then updating your current ongoing notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating)

[Example how to draw text on bitmap](http://android.okhelp.cz/create-bitmap-and-draw-text-into-bitmap-android-example/)

This will change the icon in the statusbar and visible for the user.

Comment: Like in the example there are several different possible numbers that can show up.  Is there a way to edit drawable resources on the fly, or would I have to draw out every number beforehand, and use a giant case switch statement to determine which drawable I want to use.  That sounds like a horrible method, but unless I can edit those drawables from an activity, it seems like the only option.

Comment: I would just use the Canvas API to draw on a bitmap, this is easy and quick. There is a link in my post with an example. There is no need to create a lot of images

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I believe the images for setSmallIcon must be predefined in the package.  I don't think you have the ability to edit them on the fly.